# MySQL -- create two indexes, only one appears in SHOW CREATE TABLE output

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys, constraints

In have a many-to-many linking table and I'm trying to set up two foreign keys on it. I run these two statements:

```
ALTER TABLE address_list_memberships
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_address_list_memberships_address_id
FOREIGN KEY index_address_id (address_id)
REFERENCES addresses (id);

ALTER TABLE address_list_memberships
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_address_list_memberships_list_id
FOREIGN KEY index_list_id (list_id)
REFERENCES lists (id);
```

I would expect that when I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE address_list_memberships` I'd see this:

```
[...]
KEY `index_address_id` (`address_id`),
KEY `index_list_id` (`list_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_address_list_memberships_list_id` FOREIGN KEY (`list_id`) 
    REFERENCES `lists` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_address_list_memberships_address_id` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) 
    REFERENCES `addresses` (`id`)
```

But instead I get this:

```
[...]
KEY `index_list_id` (`list_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_address_list_memberships_list_id` FOREIGN KEY (`list_id`) 
    REFERENCES `lists` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_address_list_memberships_address_id` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) 
    REFERENCES `addresses` (`id`)
```

It looks as though only one index is there. Seems to contradict the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) which say MySQL automatically creates an index on the referencing column whenever you create a foreign key.

I've noticed this only-one-index thing every time I create two FKs on a table whether I use a GUI tool such as CocoaMySQL or SQLyog, or whether I do it on the command line.

Any illumination of this mystery would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it and it works fine for me.  I copied and pasted the `ALTER` statements you wrote and here is what I get:

```
mysql> show create table address_list_memberships;

CREATE TABLE `address_list_memberships` (
  `address_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `list_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `index_address_id` (`address_id`),
  KEY `index_list_id` (`list_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_address_list_memberships_list_id` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`list_id`) REFERENCES `lists` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_address_list_memberships_address_id` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `addresses` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm using MySQL 5.0.51a on Mac OS X.

**edit:**  Try the following query to get all the indexes MySQL *thinks* exist on your table:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND table_name = 'address_list_memberships'\G
```

(I used the 'test' database for my test; you should replace this string with the name of the schema where your table is defined.)

Comment: I wonder why it worked for you but not for me. I'm using MySQL 5.0.51a on CentOS 5 (RedHat Linux clone). Since I posted, I ran `ALTER TABLE address_list_memberships ADD INDEX index_address_id (address_id)` and that worked so the index really wasn't there.

Comment: But MySQL allows you to create redundant indexes on the same column(s), so the fact that ADD INDEX worked this time doesn't necessarily mean that the key wasn't there before.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter. You still have an index on list_id. MySQL requires any foreign key constraint to also have an index on the referencing fields. Since both index_list_id and fk_address_list_memberships_list_id are built on list_id, MySQL probably sees this and uses index_list_id as the index, renaming it to fk_address_list_memberships_list_id. You could even skip declaring the index, since MySQL will do it implicitly in the version you are using.